# XStream don't convert a xml tag

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have an xml. I want to convert to object , xstream convert well all tags except one of them it gives null.

Any idea about this problem ?

**xml**:

```
  <person>
  <name>nnn</name>
  <age>aaa</age>
  <address>
    <city>ccc</city>
    <countryco</country>
  </address>
  </person>
```

**Code java**

```
  XStream _xstream = new XStream();
  _xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
  _xstream.aliasType("person", PersonType.class);
  _xstream.aliasType("address", PersonType.class);
  _xstream.aliasField("city", AddressType.class, "city");
  _xstream.aliasField("country", AddressType.class, "country");
```

When I inspect the object person , all variables are ok , but address is always `null`

i tried this :

```
_xstream.aliasType("person", PersonType.class);
_xstream.aliasType("address", AddressType.class);
_xstream.aliasField("city", AddressType.class, "city");
_xstream.aliasField("country", AddressType.class, "country");
```

but still don't work !

Answer (score 0):

In this case the usage of alias are redundant. XStream will convert the names of the fields automaticly.

How ever you adress seems to be an nested type.  You are using the same type for two aliases:

```
_xstream.aliasType("person", PersonType.class);
_xstream.aliasType("address", PersonType.class);
```

it should be

```
_xstream.aliasType("address", AddressType.class);
```

for adress alias.

Comment: Please edit your question and show me the involved classes AdressType and PersonType

Answer (score 0):

Java Code:

```
 @XStreamAlias("person")
 public class Person {

 @XStreamAlias("name")
 private String Name;

 @XStreamAlias("age")
 private long Age;

 @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "address")
 private List addresses = new ArrayList();
 }

 @XStreamAlias("adress")
 public class Address{

 @XStreamAlias("city")
 private String City;

 @XStreamAlias("country")
 private String Country;
 }
```

Main Code:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("file.xml"); // load file

XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.processAnnotations(Person.class);
xstream.processAnnotations(Address.class);

Person person = (Person) xstream.fromXML(reader);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `address` would be a reference of object `Address` in your class Person. If so then you need to do like this:

```
Person.java

public class Person{
private String name;
    private int age;
    private Address address;
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return age;}
    public String getcity(){
        return address.getCity();
    }
    public String getCountry(){
        return address.getCountry();
    }
}

Address.java

public class Address {
    private String city;
    private String country;
    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }
    public String getCountry(){
        return country;
    }
}

JAVA CODE

FileReader xmlReader = new FileReader("file.xml"); // load file

XStream stream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
stream.alias("person",Person.class);//Since in your xml file `person` is tag

Person person = (Person) stream.fromXML(xmlReader);

System.out.println("Name:"+person.getName()+"\nAge:"+person.getAge()+
           "\nCity:"+person.getCity()+"\nCountry:"+person.getCountry();
```